# When to use X2Apic Mode?

Tags: dell-poweredge, bios, cpu-architecture

I am setting up a new server (PowerEdge T130) for a small business, running Windows Server Essentials 2016.
It will be used as a file server, AV, domain controller and has some SQL databases.
I know usage ideally shouldn't be mixed, but it will have very little usage - only a few users occasionally accessing it.

I want to optimise it for speed as much as possible and am going through the BIOS settings.  One that has caught my eye is X2Apic Mode.

What does this do, and when should I not have it enabled?  I think it was Disabled by default but I have since turned it on, is that likely to cause any issues?
[image]

Comment: Note: on Dell PowerEdge 14G servers (Rx40), enabling X2APIC might cause BSOD and in rare cases, permanent hardware damage. Read this KB before using it: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-US/000146200/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some info on what [APIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programmable_Interrupt_Controller) is.

When enabled, processor x2APIC support helps operating systems run more efficiently on high core count configurations and optimizes interrupt distribution in virtualized environments. Enabled mode only provides the support necessary to the operating system. So if you have a multiprocessor system, use virtualization and also know that the operating system that you use supports APIC, you can enable the option.

Also, press F1 to get more info. Maybe the Dell note down below would provide more info on that feature.

Comment: Thanks.  What would be considered a high-core count?   And why would I NOT want to have it enabled regardless? 
Task manager reports - 1 CPU, 4 Cores, 8 Logical Processors.   Is this high enough to warrant x2APIC ?

Comment: This is for multi-processor systems, although I am not sure if virtual CPUs count as multi. Maybe they do. There is no point in enabling a service that is not used. Most it will do is waste CPU cycles during boot up in order to start something that is not required. As for your 8 Logical Processors, they are simply threads that your CPU can handle. You have 1 physical processor with 4 cores that can handle 8 threads (probably 2 per core). Hope that helps.